# how to move jquery ui dialog box to top position after opening it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Can any one tell me how i move my dialog box to top position after opening it.

```
$("#addPage").on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#addPage" ).dialog( "option", "position", { my: "center", at: "top"} );
    $( "#addPage" ).on( "dialogcreate", function( event, ui ) {$(event.target).parent().css('position', 'fixed');} );
});
```

but this is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

CSS -

```
.addPageDialogPosition {
    top: 5px ! important;
}
```

javascript -

```
$(function(){
    $("#addPage").on( "dialogopen", function( event, ui ) {
        $(event.target).parent().addClass('addPageDialogPosition');
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
    });
    $("#addPage").on( "dialogdragstart", function( event, ui ) {
        $(event.target).parent().removeClass('addPageDialogPosition');
    });
});
```